# Integration test + aspectJ + gradle

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj

I was working with maven and aspectj plugin and was fine, recently I move to gradle, I already have the configuration to build/compile with aspects and that is working fine, but for integration tests are not working fine.
I have the following configuration

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "src/main/resources/"
        }
    }

    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/test/it')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }

    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = [
                "src/main/generated"
            ]
        }
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}
```

but the aspects are not compiled/working correctly in the integration test. what I tried to do is the following configuration

```
compileIntegrationTestJava{

    sourceCompatibility="1.7"
    targetCompatibility="1.7"
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir

    dependsOn configurations.ajc.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "compileJava")

    doLast{
        ant.taskdef( resource:"org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(source:"1.7", target:"1.7",
                destDir:sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir.absolutePath, maxmem:"512m", fork:"true",
                aspectPath:configurations.aspects.asPath,
                sourceRootCopyFilter:"**/.svn/*,**/*.java",classpath:configurations.compile.asPath){
            sourceroots{
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
                sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs.each{
                    pathelement(location:it.absolutePath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error.

```
[ant:iajc] [error] build config error: bad sourceroot: \src\integrationTest\java
```

If I change the line `sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs.each` for `sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs.each`, the IT under `/src/test/it` are not being compiled and are not moved to the correct package, BUT if I put my IT test under `/src/test/java` that compile correctly.

I would like to know how to put the correct `sourceSets` to point `src/test/it` and how to add to the classpath some classes instead of add

```
sourceroots{
                sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each
```

As this makes the whole classes be added to the `clasess/test/` directory

If you have any link or guide to do this, will be truly appreciate

Comment: Hi Koitoer, did you get anywhere with this?  Since this is my question also.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this and got it working I believe.

When you say:

> I would like to know how to put the correct sourceSets to point
>   src/test/it and how to add to the classpath some classes instead of
>   add `sourceroots{...`

Do you mean 'why do you need to write all that code to add a `srcDir`'?  I'm with you!

What I believe got this working for me is:

```
configurations {
    querydslapt
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime

    ajc
    aspectpath
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjrt', version: '1.8.9'
    compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.8.9'
    aspectpath group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-aspects', version: '4.3.0.RELEASE'
    ajc 'org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.8.9'
}
```

**Where I'm only weaving with Spring-aspects such as for transactions.**

```
compileIntegrationTestJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"

    doLast {
        ant.taskdef(resource: "org/aspectj/tools/ant/taskdefs/aspectjTaskdefs.properties", classpath: configurations.ajc.asPath)
        ant.iajc(source: "1.8", target: "1.8",
                maxmem: "512m", fork: "true",
                destDir: sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir.absolutePath,
                aspectPath: configurations.aspectpath.asPath,
                classpath: classpath.asPath) {
            sourceroots {
                sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs.each { sd ->
                    if (file(sd).exists()) {
                        pathelement(location: sd.absolutePath)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The tricky part was the need to add:

```
                    if (file(sd).exists()) {
```

That was to eliminate the extra non-existant path.  That is:

`sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs` contains (absolute paths to):

- `src/integrationTest/java` and
- `src/integration-test/java`

And before I put in this guard ajc was failing with `[ant:iajc] [error] build config error: bad sourceroot: \src\integrationTest\java` just like you.  I determined this by adding this debug task (very helpful):

```
task printprojectDebug {
    doLast {
        sourceSets.integrationTest.java.srcDirs.each { println it }
        println '---- configurations.integrationTestCompile.asPath: '
        println configurations.integrationTestCompile.asPath
        println '---- configurations.aspectpath.asPath:'
        println configurations.aspectpath.asPath
        println 'end'
    }
}
```

and run `gradle printprojectDebug`.

I'm still testing to see if this is working as I'm getting errors that I haven't fully determined if is from aspect weaving problems.  But it should get you working again.

Hope my feedback helps (anyone!).