# Why gradle-aspectj doesn't pick up IntegrationTest sourceSet

Tags: gradle, aspectj

Like many others I am trying to convert a Maven project to gradle and am having problems with aspects.  I have tried using gradle-aspectj - https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj - and right out of the box it weaves main and test sources.  But I am trying to run IntegrationTests as a separate SourceSet.

The code for gradle-aspectj at https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/master/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy loops over the `project.sourceSets` so why doesn't it pick up the one for integration tests?

I have seen that most users use `antTasks-iajc` to define other SourceSets.  This isn't trivial (see [Integration test + aspectJ + gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236557/integration-test-aspectj-gradle)).  The gradle-aspectj plugin is fairly painless to setup and configure - couldn't the addition of other sourceSets be incorporated into gradle-aspectj?

Comment: Sorry, but it's a bit hard to say anything about this without a sample build.gradle, or even better, a minimal test case.

Comment: Also note that the naming for the dependencies is different if you're not using the main sourceset: https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/master/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy#L36 checks the name of the sourceset, and if it isn't main, the dependencies are looked up using the default naming convention, https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj/blob/v1.6/src/main/groovy/aspectj/AspectJPlugin.groovy#L87. This leads to names like {sourcesetname}Aspectpath

Comment: Does this default work for all SourceSets apart from main?  The simplest Use Case would be to have any additional SourceSets weave in the same way Test does - with any aspects that are declared.  Admittedly it gets a little trickier when different kinds of configurations are required.  But then if the simplest case was covered off then that would solve 90% of the Integration Test cases.

Comment: It's the same for all configurations - only the main sourceset uses a different naming convention.